# Why does JOptionPane disturb my string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting, joptionpane

I have a line of code similar to the following:

```
final String food = 
    (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Choose a food", "Food",
                                         JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                                         {"Pizza", "Hot Dog"}, "Pizza");
```

When I use the variable `food`, I get a part of the string, but also some other characters that I can't see. I am not sure what is going on. Can someone help me?

To reproduce the problem:

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("APPDATA") + File.separator + food + ".txt");
```

It is supposed to print something like this:

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Pizza.txt
```

But it actually gives the output:

```
.txtsers\userName\AppData\Roaming\Pizza
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: Are you sure you have `""Food"`? That can't compile!

Comment: You have an extra quotation mark in front of "Food". You should get rid of it.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could even compile with the extra double quote.

Comment: Sorry, no, I dont have ""Food"
let me fix that

Comment: This question begs for an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Well, i have no clue what is happening. All the characters are there, but there must be some formatting issue that the string has because it doesn't display correctly

Comment: Please show more of your code. I cant reproduce this problem... The code seems to be ok

Comment: Hold on a second check my post in a sec

Comment: How does it display if not correctly?  I just ran a test program and checked the length of the string to make sure it was correct, and it was.

Comment: That output shows you have a \r between Pizza and .txt.  Replace the food with "Pizza" and see what happens; if you have the ".txt" in a variable, test that too.

Comment: Also, why the chain of SBs instead of just + or String.Format()?  I think it'd be easier to read `System.getEnv("APPDATA") + File.separator + food + ".txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error must be somewhere else in your code.

I just ran the following code:

```
String[] options = {"Pizza", "Hot Dog"};

final String food = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a food", "Food", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, "Pizza");

System.out.println("'" + food + "'");
```

When I selected Pizza I got **Pizza** at the console. When I selected Hot Dog I got **Hot Dog**.

About the other part of your code. I just ran:

```
String[] options = {"Pizza", "Hot Dog"};

final String food = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a food", "Food", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, "Pizza");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(System.getenv("APPDATA"));
sb.append(File.separator);
sb.append(food);
sb.append(".txt");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

And got 
*C:\some folder at my computer\Hot Dog.txt* and 
*C:\some folder at my computer\Pizza.txt*.

Comment: Alright, nevermind everyone. It appears to be a StringBuilder problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, nevermind everyone. It appears that either my computer is dumb and it still isn't working, or you guys are lieing because it STILL doesn't work!!!

Comment: You are trying to do too much stuff in a single line, which makes it hard to figure out what is wrong. All I did was break your code in multiple lines and fix what wasn't compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even compile because it expects an Object[]. try new String[] {"Pizza", "Hot Dog"} instead of just {"Pizza", "Hot Dog"}

Answer (score 0):

Some Glassball guessing:

The output of `.txtsers\userName\AppData\Roaming\Pizza` looks like there was a carriage-return in your string (before the `.txt`). You can reproduce this with this code:

```
System.out.println("C:\\users\\userName\\AppData\\Roaming\\Pizza\r.txt");
```

The question would be how this carriage return got into your string. Obviously, the code you've shown in the question does not produce it.

Create a [short self contained compilable example (SSCCE)](http://pscode.org/sscce.html), and you either will find the reason on the way, or we can show you, when you post it here (add it to the question).